# TCP hole puching - How to proceed this step

Tags: java, tcp, udp, p2p, udpclient

I finished a P2P program in Java that is working perfectly in LAN range, and now I'm stuck at the well-known NAT traversal problem. I want to allow my users to connect to each other passing through the NAT boundaries (I know that is impossible to have a 100% about it). I've read a lot about the subject and, although I've understood the concept, I still have doubts doing a TCP hole puching.

What I want to do is to connect two clients to each other (they live under the same NAT), which ips are, respectively, *192.168.100.1* and *192.168.100.2* (they can connect to each other directly). They first connect to a PHP server through sockets at the port 80. The server register its public ips and ports, something like that:

**Client 1:** 200.000.000.1:1478
**Client 2:** 120.000.000.1:2547

And the Java sockets of each client returns, upon connection, for instance:

**Client 1:** Socket[addr=/xx.xx.xx.xx,port=80,localport=54632]
**Client 2:** Socket[addr=/xx.xx.xx.xx,port=80,localport=41789]

*Id est*, beyond two tcp connections open with the server through port 80, I also have the private ip, the public ip, the local port and the public port of each client. Then, that's my problem. From now on I don't know how to proceed. What I read was not very clear to me about this step.

Is necessary to have the two clients listening on public ports (*1478-2547*) or local ports (*54632-41789*)? Simultaneously making them try to connect on public or private of the other? How many other sockets I need to open? I've done some tests, but I think something is wrong (****connection refused****).

Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to proceed.

1. You could implement some kind of proxy. Both Clients connect to it (outside NAT-Barrier) and have it route their messages.
2. If you want direct connections Client2Client, your users will have to open a port on their NAT-Barrier and forward it to the local IP.

That's annoying but that's also how it works.

For Client A it's useless to know Client B's local data, because he won't be able to reach it.
To your last few questions: Local Client A listens on a port lets say X , then Local Client B has to connect to the public IP of Client A's network. Probably that's a router. There, the port has to be configured to be forwarded to Local Client A. That's all.
If you follow possibility #1 (see above) you'll have to have a public service listening on port X, to which Clients A *and* B connect. Since these will be outgoing connections to a public IP, no Holepunching is needed.

Comment: Pretty much this, you either proxy, or SNAT. Either way, SOMEONE has to be **listening** for you to open a connection.

Comment: UPnP is supported by some (many? most?) firewalls that can be used for applications to programatically request forwarding of "listen" ports.  http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Port_Forwarding

Comment: Good addition, thanks. That's basically doing the forwarding-configuration of the router transparently for the user.